# Can I have a modifiable Java file outside in a .war file? (but still connected to the .war project)

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jdbc, war

Greetings stackoverflowers,

I have a ***Java*** project in ***Eclipse*** that contains, apart from ***RESTful WebServices*** to read inputs, some programming logic that uses the inputs given and data from a connection to a Database (using the `jdbc`driver) to generate some results. The project is then exported into an `.war`file and deployed in an `Apache Tomcat Server`. So far so good.

My question is can I separate the ***Java*** file that contains the connection to the DB (to be outside the `.war`) in order to be easily modifiable?

Imagine I have 4 different DB's (testing DB, devolpment DB, production DB, etc.)...do I need to create 4 different `.war`files with different connection parameters or there is a way to have it externally to the `.war` project and change this connection parameters as I like? (but still be connected and readable by the `.war`).

*PS:* Sorry if I made any spelling mistakes, or if I violated the StackOverflow conduct. Feel free to tell me if I did, and thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection information is best handled as JNDI connection pools configured on the app server you deploy on.

Eclipse is an IDE that may have an app server like Tomcat or JBOSS running inside it.  You need to learn how to set up a JNDI connection pool for your app server.

Answer (score 0):

Use O/S Environment Variables (envvars) to store machine-specific details.

If you use Spring, you can use Spring's PropertyPlaceHolder and then use those envvars directly in spring config files.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: @duffymo not the most helpful comment. You know that AWS and Heroku use this approach right?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 4 different properties files to point to different DB.
And add system property during JVM start up to pick up the environment you want.